# Ubuntu sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Intentando resolver el siguiente error:

> Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
>     Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.46), connection timed out

Realicé la solución dada en este Post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045547/connection-refused-while-apt-get-update-ubuntu-18-04-over-proxy/1045627

Entonces ahora tengo este problema y no se como resolverlo:

```
marcos@marcos-GL553VD:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:5 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Err:7 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apandada1/brightness-controller/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.iiit.ac.in'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Es un sitio en español. Traduce tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar, ya está en español, gracias por avisar

Comment: Vió este? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751608/ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-could-not-resolve-proxy-server

Comment: Oh muchas gracias, con eso lo he solucionado, no lo había visto